# xcode core data section error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I have a table that gets data from core data. I added a section, in which there must be only one static cell. But I get an error and I can't figure out why.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

questo è il codice

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self setupFetchedResultsController];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if (section == 0) {

    return [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count];

} else if (section == 1) {

    return 1;

}

return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Category Cell";

CategoryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CategoryCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...

if (indexPath.section == 0) {

    NSLog(@"section %i",indexPath.section);

    Category *category = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    cell.categoryNameLabel.text = category.name;
    cell.categoryNumberItemsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",category.containItem.count];

} else {
    //Static cell
}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint, this will tell you the line of your code that is crashing.

Comment: programmatically, there are no mistakes in my opinion. Is the first time I use storyboards, maybe there's something wrong.

Comment: are you sure this [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; is doing right?

Comment: I think so, if i set one section, it works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two tableView datasource methods are not consistent.

In `numberOfRowsInSection`, you return the total count of the fetched results controller's `fetchedObjects`.

In `cellForRow...`, you are using the fetched results controller's `objectAtIndexPath` method.

You should be obtaining the section info object and getting the row count from there, as per the documentation:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[<#Fetched results controller#> sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

Comment: thanks, the error was here, I have not implemented this method - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return @"";
}